what are the necessary parameters need when using in constainer style `display : "flex" in react?`
I'm new to react so as the title implies, my question is "what is flex in display : "flex" in react?"
when reading multiple documentation it says that it's for flexbox, which from my understanding is for laying out the components but this just further confuses me. I assume that in this case, the height and width are what flexbox will use to distance itself from other components if I understand correctly.
const ColoredCircleIcon = ({ color = 'orange', size = 50 }: ColoredCircleIconProps): JSX.Element => {

  const containerStyles: React.CSSProperties = {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    height: '100vh',    // Full viewport height
    width: '100vw',     // Full viewport width
  };

  return (
    <div style={containerStyles}>
      <FaCircle color={color} size={size} /> {/* Circle Icon */}
    </div>
  );
};

in the react documentation it shows code examples but without any display : "flex"
which also begs the question, what are the parameters that display : "flex" will need for the flexbox algorithm. And how does one find the list of parameters?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

The technology you're looking for is called CSS, not React.

@David thank you for the clarification of the technology! :)

@JaredSmith i've tweaked the question a bit more now, not sure if this is good or not

Flexbox is its own way of laying out a div with many different parameters depending on what you want it to do. If you're looking for details, a treasure trove of them can be found at https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp
